# form search with button javascript - html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have this HTML code of a form that the user must fill in so that there is a return for a result, my question is: how can I stop the button from returning results once the first click is made?

Every time that the user push de button it give an create de result in the web and I want to stop the creation of the element with only one click. Maybe it has to have oneclick event in the button?

HTML:

```
<form class="border border-light p-2" onsubmit="save_data(event)">
    <input type="text" id="departamento" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="ingrese departamento">
    <input type="text" id="localidad" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="ingrese localidad">

    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="coneat"  placeholder="ingrese indice coneat">
        
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="hectareas"  placeholder="ingrese hectareas">

    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
<div id="resultado">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function save_data (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const departamento = $('#departamento').val();
  const localidad = $('#localidad').val();
  const coneat = $('#coneat').val();
  const hectareas = $('#hectareas').val();

  buscaCampo(valoresFormulario);
}
 
function buscaCampo(buscacampo) {
  if (buscacampo.departamento) {
    let element = document.getElementById("resultado")
    switch (buscacampo.departamento.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
      case "artigas":
        const el1 = document.createElement("p");
        var text = document.createTextNode(innerHTML = `Mejor resultado: departamento: ${newcampo1.departamento}, indice coneat: ${newcampo1.coneat}, hectareas: ${newcampo1.hectareas}, localidad: ${newcampo1.localidad}`);
        el1.appendChild(text);
        console.log(el1)
        console.log(document)
        console.log(element)
        element.appendChild(el1)
        break;
        case "salto":
        const el2 = document.createElement("p")
        var text = document.createTextNode(innerHTML = `Mejor resultado: departamento: ${newcampo2.departamento}, indice coneat: ${newcampo2.coneat}, hectareas: ${newcampo2.hectareas}, localidad: ${newcampo2.localidad}`);
        el2.appendChild(text);
        console.log(el2)
        console.log(document)
        console.log(element)
        element.appendChild(el2)
        break;
        case "florida":
        const el3 = document.createElement("p")
        var text = document.createTextNode(innerHTML = `Mejor resultado: departamento: ${newcampo3.departamento}, indice coneat: ${newcampo3.coneat}, hectareas: ${newcampo3.hectareas}, localidad: ${newcampo3.localidad}`);
        el3.appendChild(text);
        console.log(el3)
        console.log(document)
        console.log(element)
        element.appendChild(el3)
        break;
        case "tacuarembo":
        const el4 = document.createElement("p")
        var text = document.createTextNode(innerHTML = `Mejor resultado: departamento: ${newcampo4.departamento}, indice coneat: ${newcampo4.coneat}, hectareas: ${newcampo4.hectareas}, localidad: ${newcampo4.localidad}`);
        el4.appendChild(text);
        console.log(el4)
        console.log(document)
        console.log(element)
        element.appendChild(el4)
        break;
      default:
        const el5 = document.createElement("p")
        var text = document.createTextNode(`no se ha encontrado resultado`);
        el5.appendChild(text);
        console.log(el5)
        console.log(document)
        console.log(element)
        element.appendChild(el5)
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please learn how to [ask], and create a [mcve]? Thanks!

Comment: `valoresFormulario` is nothing

Comment: I have this 
  const valoresFormulario = {
    departamento,
    localidad,
    hectareas,
    coneat,
  };

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will suit you:

```
<button onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-info btn-block" 
type="submit">Buscar</button>


function submit() {
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
}
```